# Non-rectangular drop down menus

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, transform

I have to implement the following non-rectangular drop down menu. (see picture)

http://postimg.org/image/fmzro5rfl/

It needs to work with IE8 and up. Each of the trapezoid product icon divs will be highlighted when mouse-over.

Should I use image maps, CSS Sprites or CSS transformation to implement this?

- I can use PNG if needed
- I don't mind having extra helper libraries just to deal with IE8/9

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/ad9Bj/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    background: orange;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding-left:40px;
    padding-right:40px;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    color: #fff;
}
ul li:hover {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/ZV01sGZ.png') no-repeat;
}
```